# Rails5 API + Angular2 Frontend + static HTML homepage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, performance

Working on an app that has a Rails 5.0 API backend, and an Angular2 front-end, but the Angular app is so large, I can't have it load whenever someone lands on the app's home page (/) since the homepage is just information about the app and a call-to-action to sign-up.

Is there a way to have the frontpage (/), sign-up page (/sign-up), and sign-in page (/sign-in) be static HTML so they load fast, and the angular app doesn't load immediately, then, once the user has signed up or signed in, they are redirected to the Angular app?

I'm wondering where do I put the static pages? In the /public folder of the rails API, or is there a place in the Angular app where I can store a static page like this, without the whole Angular app loading when you go to that page?

Comment: I'm not sure why u decide to use Rails and Angular together.. U can use easily Rails for Static, Login, Register, BackEnd (for everything).. What's ur usage for using both?

Comment: @LiborZahrádka The Angular frontend is much faster, once it has loaded. ;)

Comment: I can easily build Rails front-end website with less than 0.5s load speed.. It depends what u're using (large images, unnecessary JS)

Comment: @LiborZahrádka I figured out I could use the proxy config for my Angular app. :D

Comment: Too complitated for that 

Comment: @LiborZahrádka Is there a performance issue?

Comment: No if u can figured out there is not

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Create controllers for APIs, Angular and also StaticPages controller.

Static pages controller should have methods like `home`, `sign-up`, `sign-in` and their routes & views pairs,

Then create controllers for APIs and controller with method for  Angular views.

Comment: Interesting! I never thought of using a controller to serve a static page. Is that slower than putting a static page in "/public" ?

Comment: @Bago I think that is standard approach. Even if you serve pure HTML pages, it is normal to create controller for static pages and add methods for each page because that way you can easier manipulate routes and add some ruby (erb) code inside if it will be needed in the future. That is described in Michael Hartl's book (https://www.railstutorial.org/) for Rails 4 which is accepted as standard guide for Rails. Now I can't really tell if it is faster or not, but the difference in load speed is unnoticeable.

Comment: After a lot of researching, I think I have to switch my whole setup around, so that rails is the app that is reached first. Right now I have Angular as the "main" app, and it makes it impossible to serve a static file on "/" without loading the Angular app entirely.

Comment: Yes wrap Angular inside Rails rather than vice versa or saparately

Comment: I can't find any examples of this. It's really hard to google... LOL Every example I see loads the angular app right away. Doesn't seem very practical in the real world. Last time I checked, my Angular app was 3.2MB........

Comment: @BagoCamembert This is Angular1+Rails4 example I made few months back: https://github.com/kunokdev/flightmap and here is guide http://angular-rails.com/

Comment: Have you succeed?

Comment: I am abandoning Angular2.

Comment: @BagoCamembert The guide didn't help? What are you going to use instead of Angular ?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd probably try moving the current `src/index.html` to `src/something-else.html` and then make `src/index.html` static.

I don't know if Angular CLI/Webpack will automatically pick up your `src/something-else.html` and put it into `dist` (where Rails' `public` directory is probably symlinked to), but in any case, that's what I'd try to make happen.

Comment: I actually, got rid of the symlink, and put back the public folder, and it still loads the Angular app on "/". I'm trying to figure out how to load the angular app on /#/ because I want "/" to be static. changing base href has no effect.

Comment: Actually, if I could serve the app on "/dashboard" that would be fine too. For some reason I can't find where in the config to set this.

Comment: OK I figured one thing out. I had a proxy config problem. Now I can get the app to run on "/app" but what is still happening is if you land on "/", the angular app loads, and redirects you to "/app". So I guess this is more of a rails question. How do I get rails to handle "/" on its own instead of passing the request on to the Angular app?

Comment: I'm guessing I need to hide the static "/" page inside the angular app?

Comment: I would keep the symlink and change `client/src/index.html` into a static HTML file that doesn't reference Angular at all. That's equivalent to having a static `public/index.html` (as long as you can get Webpack to copy `index.html` into `dist` for you, which I'm sure you can).

Comment: Doing that over-writes the whole app. So index.html shows up at every URL.

Comment: I think the issue is that my "main" app is Angular and that is where the user lands. I need to turn it around and have Rails serve as my frontend, and on a specific route like "/app", Rails serves the angular app.

Comment: I believe you could do that by keeping `public` and then symlinking `public/app` to `dist`.

Comment: That has no effect. The Angular app loads at "/" and "/app". Thanks for your help though. I'm thinking I may need to abandon Angular.